# MVC app with SQL Server CE - errors in generated controller code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-ce

I am starting a new MVC application using .sdf database in App_Data. I created one table (Events) there, also I created it in Models:

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string Presenter { get; set; }
    public int NumberAttendees { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
}
```

The context:

```
public class AcademicCalendarDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="AcademicCalendarDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Events.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

The problem is when I create a controller (EventController) 
it does create it but with compilation errors everywhere in the code. An example in:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    Event event = db.Events.Find(id);
    if (event == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(event);
}
```

`event` has compilation error: "} is expected".

`if` has compilation error: "Invalid if token in class".

`return` has compilation error: "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods".

It is weird because the controller is generated, and it should not have compilation errors.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Is the ActionResult method placed outside the controller class?

Comment: No it is inside the class, it is a generated scaffolding code. I think it is an issue with EF6 not supporting scaffolding. I will investigate more. Thanks